# Django : select all columns when innerjoin using extra without foreignkey

Tags: mysql, django, orm, inner-join

I have two tables and they do not have foreign key or relationship. However, I have to do join and get all columns from both tables. This is the query I've made.

```
query = Sms.objects \
        .extra(tables=['product'], where=['product.id=sms.sms_id'])
```

When I printed raw query, I could check it only gets tables from Sms model, not from product model. Is there any way to get columns from product model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need some [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/)

Obviously you will need to customize your SQL depending on what your needs are and how you want/need to access the data. But here's a very simple example:

```
crsr = dbconnection.cursor()
myresults = crsr.execute("SELECT A.*, B.* FROM A,B WHERE A.ID=B.ID")
for myresult in myresults:
    print('{} {} {}'. format(myresult[0], myresult [1], myresult[2]))
crsr.close()
```

The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/) on this subject is very good. This is a powerful feature of Django. But with great power...